# SVG circle wobbles in rotation animation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I've tried a very simple CSS animation of rotating a div containing an SVG circle. For some reason the circle wobbles. The expected behavior is for the circle to appear static. Why does this happen?

html:

```
<div id="circle"><svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         viewBox="0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
<circle style="fill:#1B1464;" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg></div>
```

css:

```
#circle {
  width: 50px;
  animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotating {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/se7en/pen/OMZRbJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect your #circle div you'll see that it has a height of 54px rather than 50px - so it throws off the rotation a bit

Answer (score 1):

As Tom Walpole mentioned, it seems like there is an extra px on the SVG height. Adding **display:block** on the SVG seems to remove extra px.

Comment: Thanks. display:block didn't work on firefox but specifying a height did!